# CSS Fixed Header Footer

Tags: html, css

After spending 3 days unsuccessfully searching the web for a solution I thought I'd ask my own question...

I want to design a page that has a fixed header of 50px, a fixed footer of 30px that is always at the bottom of the screen regardless of the body's content, a navigation treeview on the left side that may scroll if content is more than will fit on the page, and a main content area that uses the remainder of the screen.

I would like this to be written using pure css and div statements.

Comment: Let me google it for you: http://www.cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/, http://www.treeview.net/tv/instructions.asp....

Comment: Man in short, you are asking us to design a website for you. Just follow the links @nevermind has provided. Don't give up and you will do great. Ask any specific question if you have. Also make sure that your question is not asked before.

Comment: The solution is to code it yourself. This is pretty basic HTML and CSS, this is not a site where you tell us what you want and we code it for you. You show us what you have so far and where you have got stuck and we can point you in the right direction. At the moment your stuck on using Google.... Not sure who can help you with that. [Let me Google that for you](http://tinyurl.com/q6b39eh)

Comment: Guys, sorry for my horrible attempt at asking a question. I didn't mean to imply that I wanted you to do my work for me. Heres a fiddle of what I have so far... https://jsfiddle.net/BamaDan/d2yr01x1/1/

The panel in blue I'm trying to make 100% of the body minus the header and footer. If the treeview (which will not show in the fiddle) is more than 100% of the body then the user should be able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ask people to do your homework for you. At least try to program something yourself and research a lot before asking for help with your code. Only ask for help if you really can't figure it out yourself.

Anyway, the answer to your question lies in the title: `fixed`.

[I made this really quick for you](http://jsfiddle.net/x3c504k6/2/).

Use this example for in the near future and use this advice in the far future.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the calc function, that should make your life easier. There are many ways to do what you want, here's one of them using perfect sizing.

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.main{
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7b4emfb/

That should get you started. But yeah, you should google more. Learn how `position`, `float` and `display` work and you shouldn't have any problem.